# How to tell "where class definition of forward reference in type hints is" to Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

How to tell "where class definition of forward reference in type hints is" to Sphinx?
How to avoid lost parameter (in Sphinx documentation) whose type is defined by forward reference of type hints?

I use sphinx-apidoc to write the documentation of my Python program.
I'm using forward reference of type hints defined in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) like this:

```
# In file A/A.py

class A:
    def a(self, param: 'MyClass') -> None:
        """docstring here"""
        pass
```

MyClass is not imported to avoid circular imports. Of course, the program works fine because type hints are ignored at runtime.

When I run sphinx-apidoc and make html, the following warning (name 'MyClass' is not defined) appears.

```
$ sphinx-apidoc -f -o doc .
Creating file doc/A.rst
$ make html
...
reading sources... [100%] main
path/to/A/A.rst:XX: WARNING: error while formatting arguments for A.A.a: name 'MyClass' is not defined
looking for now-outdated files... none found
...
build succeeded, 1 warnings.

Build finished. The HTML pages are in _build/html.
```

In the generated html, the method 'a' has no parameter like this:

```
A module

class A

    a() -> None
       docstring here
```

In the context with import MyClass (without circular imports), generated html has the parameter like this:

```
A module

class A

    a(param: MyClass) -> None
       docstring here
```

My Environment:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
$ pip3 --version
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
$ pip3 freeze | grep Sphinx
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Sphinx==1.5.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accord to sphinx issues tracker, they fix this on sphinx 1.6. Maybe try with that version. I never try so this is just a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. You may mean [Issue #3494](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3494). I will try the fixed version.